# RxJS not correctly combing the result of a secondary http get

Tags: angular, rxjs

I have a searchbox that is serviced by three seperate search APIs; you can either enter a string or a number. The string value is pretty straightforward, just returns the found results -- this can be none or up to ten. For the numbers, it is either no results or a single result, but a second GET must be made in order to complete the result. The input has a debounce of 300ms and shouldn't start searching until there's three characters entered.

My problem is that in the case of a number, the second http call is made but never actually used in the result set. The MapId function needs to do something else -- a promise is obviously not the way to go.

- Would it be better to use forkJoin instead of combineLatest?
- I've tried flatMap, but couldn't get that to work in combination with forkJoin.
- I'm kinda lost now. It shouldn't be that hard to do a get, check the results and do a second get if needed, in combination with the subscription waiting in the Angular component.

Angular component file:

```
searchTerm$ = new Subject<string>();
filterData$;

onFiltering(args: FilteringEventArgs): void {
    this.searchTerm$.next(args.text);
}

setupSearchDebouncer(): void {
    this.filterData$ = this.searchTerm$
        .pipe(
            debounceTime(300),
            switchMap(s =>
                iif(() => s.length >= 3,
                    this.searchService.find(s)
                        .pipe(
                            map((result) => {
                                return result.results
                            }),
                        ),
                    of<Result[]>([])
                ))
        );

    this.filterData$.subscribe(r => {
        this.filterArgs.updateData(r);
    });
}
```

And the RxJS service file:

```
find(searchQuery: string) {
    return combineLatest(
        this.apiService1.search(searchQuery).pipe(),
        this.apiService2.search(searchQuery).pipe(),
        this.apiService3.search(searchQuery).pipe()
    ).pipe(
        map(([stringResult, idResult1, idResult2]) => {
            if (idResult1.length > 0 || idResult2.length > 0) {
                return this.mapName(idResult1, idResult2);
            }
            else {
                return this.mapId(stringResult);
            }
        })
    );
}

mapId(stringResult): SearchResult {
    // do some mapping
    return result;
}

mapName(idResult1, idResult2): SearchResult {
    const result = new SearchResult();

    let id = undefined;
    if (idResult1 && idResult1.length > 0) {
        id = idResult1[0].Id;
    }
    else if (idResult2 && idResult2.length > 0) {
        id = idResult2[0].Id;
    }

    this.apiService.fetchName(id).toPromise().then(succes => {
        result.results = [{ name: succes[0].name, id: id }];
    });
    return result;
}
```

Comment: So the second request is `this.apiService.fetchName(id)` that you want to execute only on some condition?

Comment: Yes, mapName should only be used (and result in the second http get) when there is a result in either idResult1 or idResult2. (Fixed a typo; had mapId and mapName mixed around, sorry).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`combineLatest` is probably the best option here because you want to trigger search when any of the sources emit. `forkJoin` would emit just once when all sources complete so it wouldn't work if the sources are Subjects. This depends on what `this.apiService1.search(searchQuery)` does inside.

So you can just make sure you always return an Observable from `mapName` with `of()`:

```
mapName(idResult1, idResult2): Observable<SearchResult> {
    const result = new SearchResult();
    ...

    if (id) { // or whatever condition you need
      return this.apiService.fetchName(id).pipe(
        map(succes => {
          result.results = [{ name: succes[0].name, id: id }];
          return result;
        }),
      );
    }
    return of(result);
}
```

Then in the main chain you'll use `mergeMap` instead of `map` and again make sure you always return an Observable with `of()`:

```
mergeMap(([stringResult, idResult1, idResult2]) => {
  if (idResult1.length > 0 || idResult2.length > 0) {
     return this.mapName(idResult1, idResult2);
  } else {
     return of(this.mapId(stringResult));
  }
}),
```

Comment: All the apiservice.search and apiservice.fetchName calls are http.gets -- they all return regular observables.

Changing the if-then construct to work with observables and then let mergeMap figure it out was the trick. Would something like an iif() or defer() be an option instead of the simple if/then? To keep it properly RxJS-y.

Comment: You can use `iif()` instead of `if-else` statement (or ternary operator `? ... : ...`) but not `defer()` (you would need `if` inside it anyway). I think `iif()` is rarely used because it's just more obvious to use plain `if-else`.